# Best practices - Installing a new SSD to verify it is good

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd, reliability

When I install a new HDD into a computer, I follow the following steps:

1. Disconnect power from the computer
2. Discharge static electricity and ground myself and my work surface
3. Hook up the HDD's cable(s)
4. Turn on the computer
5. Partition the drive as 1 giant partition
6. Format the partition
7. Use a tool I wrote that writes a predictable sequence of bytes onto the entire partition
8. Turn off the computer (to ensure caches are empty and to cause the heads to park)
9. Turn on the computer
10. Use a tool I wrote that reads all the content from the partition and verifies it is the same data written in step 7
11. Re-partition the drive as desired, format the partitions as wanted, install software / copy data
12. Use the computer with the new drive, hoping I got a good drive (maintaining backups, of course)

That process has successfully worked for me for many years.  I've never lost any data by following my steps.

I'm now about to replace a laptop's HDD with a new SSD.  This will be the first time I've performed this task.

I've been quite busy, and today is the last day a return is allowed for the SSD.  So I'm not going to have much time to install it and get it going (I have many additional projects for the day).

Similar to the steps I outlined above, what are the best practices for replacing a laptop's HDD with an SSD?  Or are the steps above also ideal for an SSD?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't bother with the "writing predictable bytes" steps as you are unnecessarily using up write cycles that may get wear levelled in odd ways by the controller. The controller and obfuscation may result in some blocks being written and rewritten multiple times. Everything might be written once, but you have no guarantee what is happening at the flash level. Even on a hard drive the writing step is largely irrelevant, so long as you can *read* every sector the surface is probably fine. "Best practice" is a vague and fuzzy thing, the "best" thing to do is use the drive.

Comment: Sure, it's thorough, but largely unnecessary. Clone old drive to new drive, remove old drive, see if it boots. Done.

Comment: @Mokubai I agree... I think there is no point to verify each sector on an SSD because it's likely impossible without a very low level tool.  Also, since it's just a bunch of chips, I think you would really only need to check every chip instead of every sector.

Answer (score 2):

With an SSD you don't have to bother with all these steps and verifications.

When you format the disk, this usually uses the TRIM functions that
erases the whole disk in one operation.

While the SSD is powered up, the firmware does housekeeping jobs that
include sector verification and remapping if required.

My advice : Pop the disk into the computer, don't format if it's already
formatted correctly, and just use it.

To be sure that it's of perfect health, examine the SMART data of the
disk, which will tell if any serious errors have happened to it.
A sample utility for displaying SMART data is
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).